# Defining colours programmatically and using them in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, colors, interface-builder

I want to customize the colours of an App reusing the same elements but changing the colours.

These elements are simple Views, UIButton, UILabel, etc. nothing fancy. The colours may come from a XML or plist I will preload and parse to UIColor.

Yes, I can create an outlet from each of them and set them manually, but I got hundreds of elements and I want to avoid this path.

I tried IBInspectable, without luck, I’m looking for a widespread solution, all views, all VCs.

I am coding in Objective-C by the way...

Could you suggest any approach on how should I do this?

Comment if you want more detailing…

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple options...

1. Subclass your UI elements, and use `MYUIButton` instead of `UIButton`, for example, or
2. Look at UIAppearance proxy - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance - Using that, you can set default appearance characteristics for the whole app.

Example:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[UILabel appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

If you include those two lines (often done in AppDelegate / didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), *every* `UIButton` in your app will have a yellow background, and *every* `UILabel` will have an orange background.

(However, you will not see these changes in Interface Builder)

---

**Edit:**

As Charles mentions in his comment, you can create subclasses and then apply appearance changes to only those classes.

Suppose you have 3 button "types" that you want to apply a "color scheme" to - dark-blue, medium-blue, light-blue or dark-red, medium-red, light-red, etc. You could take the approach of creating DarkUIButton, MediumUIButton and LightUIButton subclasses. Then, when you load your color scheme...

```
[[DarkUIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:scheme.darkcolor];
[[MediumUIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:scheme.mediumcolor];
[[LightUIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:scheme.lightcolor];
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I mean, but "not all" Buttons and Labels are orange, I got many views with diverse colouring. In case of 1. What is my win with subclassing?

Comment: If you create a UIButton subclass -- e.g. MyActionButton for all 'action' button, which should have a 'action' background color defined in your XML/plist -- , you can call [[MyActionButton appearance] setBackgroundColor: action] which will change all and only 'MyActionButton's background without you having to modify all of them individually.Beware appearance only affects items not already in a window.

Comment: It depends on just how much customization you need, and how many different "things" need to be affected. I'll edit my answer with a little more detail.

Comment: I can't do that, I got dozens of views, buttons and labels using different colours... :-( Also, most of them are not hooked to their controller, I'm looking for a way to avoid doing that... It's a big big App.

Comment: Wellllll.... you're going to need *some* way to identify them. Are there distinctive features that you could use? Such as: any view that is 100x100 falls in Category A, 150x150 Category B, 200x100 cat C, etc? Maybe show an example of a typical set of elements?